# float return from jni to java received wrong result

Tags: java, floating-point, java-native-interface

I've got a function that returns float from JNI native to Java.  This should be a straightforward call but I'm getting strange result.

In my test case I'm returning value 1.61863e+010 into java.  The code is simply:

```
cout << result << endl;  cout.flush(); // get 1.61863e+010
return (jfloat) result;
```

(Just to clarify, if cout.precision(6), I get 16186300000.000000)

However my Java code is receiving 1.61863004E10.  When I use

```
DecimalFormat formatter = new DecimalFormat("###,###.######");
System.out.println(formatter.format(result));
```

I get 16,186,300,416.

Where does this 416 come from?
I thought jfloat and float are both 32bit IEEE float, so there shouldn't be any lost of precision.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 6):

You're using a `float`, which only has 7 decimal digits of precision (23 bits of mantissa, with the implicit bit for normalized numbers). Therefore you should regard anything *after* that as effectively noise. Your value isn't actually changing - it's just that the displayed representation differs between Java and your C++ implementation.

Comment: Which means, in my case, the best way is to return by string? i.e., do float to jstring in jni, then parse string to float again in java?

Comment: @user1086579: Why would you try to do that? The number is coming back correctly from the C++ to the Java. Just because the string representation differs doesn't mean you've got the wrong answer. If you parse the string in Java you'll still get the same float back, with the 416 at the end.

Answer (score 3):

Its the C++ program which is lileky to be rounding to 7 significant figures which is the precision of a `float`. If you round the value in Java to 7 places you will give the same number.  When you use DecimalFormat it will print the nearest whole number by default.

```
System.out.println("(float) " + 16186300000.0 + 
                   " is actually " + new BigDecimal((float) 16186300000.0));
```

prints

```
(float) 1.61863E10 is actually 16186300416
```